# splitting a tuple into N-element tuples

Tags: c++, template, lambda, c++20, variadic

This nice hack should allow you to split a tuple into N-element tuples, thereby effectively splitting a tuple into pairs, triples, ... For example, this allows you to split an input parameter pack, into N-element tuples. Your thoughts?

```
template <std::size_t N>
constexpr auto split(auto&& t) noexcept
{
  static_assert(std::tuple_size_v<std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(t)>> &&
    !(std::tuple_size_v<std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(t)>> % N));
  return [&]<auto ...I>(std::index_sequence<I...>) noexcept
    {
      return std::make_tuple([&]<auto K, auto ...J>(
        std::index_sequence<J...>) noexcept
        {
          return std::forward_as_tuple(std::get<K + J>(
            std::forward<decltype(t)>(t))...);
        }.template operator()<N * I>(std::make_index_sequence<N>())...
      );
    }(std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<
      std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(t)>> / N>());
}
```

Usage:

```
auto foo(auto&& ...a)
{
  auto const f([&](auto&&, auto&&)
    {
    }
  );

  return std::apply([&](auto&& ...t)
    {
      return (std::apply(f, std::forward<decltype(t)>(t)), ...);
    },
    split<2>(std::forward_as_tuple(a...))
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Corner-cases needing manual handling by the caller are the bane of correct and generic code.

   Remove them as possible, even if it would slightly complicate the implementation (it doesn't here). If it would impair efficiency that would necessitate more careful consideration, but might still be acceptable.

   1. Splitting an empty tuple is trivial.
   2. Allowing the last tuple to be shorter removes that corner-case too.
2. Make it SFINAE-friendly. Check applicability at overload-resolution using SFINAE, requires-clause, or concepts, not afterwards when it causes a hard error.
   See [an example for thoroughly checking the tuple-like protocol on SO](//stackoverflow.com/questions/68443804/c20-concept-to-check-tuple-like-types).
3. Considering you depend on C++20 features, using C++17 CTAD instead of `std::make_tuple` would be appropriate.
4. Using an explicit template-argument on the lambda is a pointless complication.

```
template <class T>
concept tuple_like_cvref = tuple_like<std::remove_cvref_t<T>>;

template <std::size_t N> requires(!!N)
constexpr auto split(tuple_like_cvref auto&& t) noexcept {
    constexpr auto n = std::tuple_size_v<std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(t)>>;
    return [&]<auto...I>(std::index_sequence<I...>){
        return std::tuple{
            [&]<auto...J>(std::index_sequence<J...>){
                constexpr auto M = I * N;
                return std::forward_as_tuple(std::get<M + J>(
                    std::forward<decltype(t)>(t)
                )...);
            }(std::make_index_sequence<I < n / N ? N : n % N>())...
        };
    }(std::make_index_sequence<(n + N - 1) / N>());
}
```

See [live on coliru](//coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fcf7d677c72289a7).